# CSRF token stored in one variable and used it for android web services

Tags: codeigniter, csrf

I have used CSRF token with regenerate option.but it giving error while load the webservices in android application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. in codeigniter if the form tag is present the csrf token generated automatically. Other than that not having any option